# Automating Xcode Build Information Modifications via TeamCity

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, teamcity

Integrating a straight forward XCode with TeamCity is pretty straight forward. With the latest version, it's native support for building iOS projects seems good.

However, what about automating modifications to the project to itself prior to build? Things like:

- Set the version string / build counter based on TeamCity values
- Set the Build Identifier based on configuration type

What are some best practices for approaching this? Sure, I can shell out and modify the Xcode Project via scripts but that seems messy and error prone.

Are there any other options?

Is it possible to have the `Bundle Identifier`, `Version`, `Build` etc to pull their values from an external file that I could create as a build step prior to build?

Also - is there any API to allow TeamCity to Archive and Submit the app to (Apple) TestFlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily use a script to set the bundle ID, version&build numbers - these are all stored in the Info.plist file, which is just a regular property list (XML) file.

You can find an example script here, which sets the build-number to our [continuous integration service](https://www.bitrise.io)'s related environment variable: https://github.com/bitrise-io/bitrise-script-collection/blob/master/bash/set_xcode_project_build_number.sh

Regarding iTunes Connect deploy: there's no official API to deploy apps to the new Apple service, but you can find a couple of gems which can provide this feature. We use [shenzhen](https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen) and [deliver](https://github.com/KrauseFx/deliver), through Bitrise/Open Step Lib [build](https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-deploy-to-itunesconnect-shenzhen) - [steps](https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-deploy-to-itunesconnect-deliver).